# how does %*% work?

Tags: r

I just started to learn R. If I create a matrix M2:

```
M2 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = 2,ncol = 2,byrow = TRUE)
```

Then type in `M2%*%M2`, it returns

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]   15   22
```

Can someone explain how does `%*%`operator work? I have no clue. Thanks for help!

Comment: Just type `help('%*%')` in your console

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math question, not programming. But no point in migrating it because there's already a duplicate at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2252283/definition-of-matrix-multiplication

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize it's a math question until I saw the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication means that the rows of the left (from `%*%`) matrix are multiplied on the columns of the right matrix: `result[i, j] <- M_left[i, ] * M_right[, j]`
E.g., for your case `7` was obtained as `1*1 + 2*3`